# Как правильно настроить checkBox1_CheckedChanged

Tags: c#, winforms

**При исходном запуске программы**:
1. Режим - **исходный**.
- checkBox1 - без галочки;
- textBox2 - режим редактирования; цвет фона белый;

Дальше начинаю ставить/ убирать галочку всё работает согласно описанного ниже сценария.

**Требуемый сценарий.**
0. Запускаю программу.
1. Режим - **исходный**.
- checkBox1 - без галочки;
- textBox2 - режим чтения. цвет фона серый;
2. Режим - рабочий.
- checkBox1 - с галочкой;
- textBox2 - режим редактирования. цвет фона белый;

**Вопрос.**
Как сделать, чтобы после запуска программы было checkBox1 - без галки, а textBox2 в режиме чтения?

```
  namespace shbl_pust
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        // checkBox1.Checked == false - без птички;
        // checkBox1.Checked == true - c птичкой;


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {        

        }
        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)sender; // приводим отправителя к элементу типа CheckBox
            if (checkBox1.Checked == false)
            {
                textBox2.ReadOnly = true;
                textBox2.BackColor = Color.Gainsboro;
            }
            else
            {
                textBox2.ReadOnly = false;
                textBox2.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
        }              


        private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        // КОД.... 
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{        
  checkBox1.Checked = false;
  checkBox1_CheckedChanged(checkBox1, null);
}
```